# Guacamole Deprecated-Declarations issues on Make

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, compiler-errors, virtualbox, guacamole

I'm trying to install Guacamole 1.4.0 on a 22.04 Ubuntu (running from a Virtual Machine) according to the following tutorial : [Install and Use Guacamole on Ubuntu](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-use-guacamole-on-ubuntu/).

I'm stuck on **Step 3: Build the Guacamole Server From Source**, at the **6th Step**.

When running the command `make`:

- I encounter a `all warning being treated as errors`
- Those warnings are **`-WError=deprecated-declarations`**
- They appear in `libguac_common_ssh_la-key.lo`
- `Since OpenSSL 3.0 rsa_key is deprecated`

**I tried:**

- `-Wno-deprecated` : Doesn't change anything
- Modifying the `./configure` file
- Checking for more updated versions (1.4.0 is the latest)

**The solution seems to be here:**

- The [GUACAMOLE-1602](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-1602?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17533478#comment-17533478) is the same thing as I have
- It is said *"This has already been resolved. The line of code in question doesn't exist in the current source on git"*

**Questions:**

- How can I get the version that corrects this issue? I can't find it.
- Do you have another solution to help?

Comment: You should add the `-Wno-error` option to the compile line.  This will turn warnings back into warnings, and not errors. It's pretty much always wrong to ship officially released packages with `-Werror` enabled.  That's great for development, but it just causes pain for users of the release.

Comment: "make -Wno-error" doesn't change anything, am I missing something?

Comment: I said "to the compile line" not to the make line.  `-Wno-error` is an option to the compiler (GCC), not to make.  You have to figure out what make variable(s) contain the compiler options.  I don't know anything about this project, but if it follows the usual rules and conventions for source code releases, you should be able to use something like `make CFLAGS='-O2 -Wno-error'`.  If it doesn't follow the usual conventions you'll have to either examine the makefile yourself to figure it out, or get advice from someone who knows about this particular source code (it's not a makefile issue).

Comment: Thanks! The command `make CFLAGS='-O2 -Wno-error'` worked!

Answer (score 1):

You should install the guacamole server from the github [repository](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-server) instead.
As the dev team precised [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-1553) that they fixed the issue but they still have not updated the official release.